# Get percentage for cohort day and daycount

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a cohort retention data frame

```
> cohortData
           cohort dayCount count
    1  25/10/2016        0   238
    2  25/10/2016        1   137
    3  25/10/2016        2    78
    4  25/10/2016        3    32
    5  25/10/2016        4    21
    6  25/10/2016        5    25
    7  26/10/2016        0   134
    8  26/10/2016        1    97
    9  26/10/2016        2    49
    10 26/10/2016        3    22
    11 26/10/2016        4    22
    12 27/10/2016        0   136
    13 27/10/2016        1    88
    14 27/10/2016        2    38
    15 27/10/2016        3    15
    16 28/10/2016        0   138
    17 28/10/2016        1    25
    18 28/10/2016        2    19
    19 29/10/2016        0   144
    20 29/10/2016        1    28
    21 30/10/2016        0   135
```

What I want to do is add a percent column to get a % of count against each cohort and daycount of 0 so for cohort 25/10/2016 percentage values for dayCount 0 through 2 would be 238/238, 137/238, 78/238.

I have looked at table.prop but was not able to get the result I want, I have tried doing a `cohortData$count / (by=list(cohortData$cohort, cohortData$dayCount==0))` but that is not correct and just gives errors.

I can convert the data into a NxN matrix, get a 2nd matrix to find % values and then unlist it and join back with the data frame above but I am sure there should be a much simpler and elegant way to go about it ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution would be this approach:

```
library(dplyr)

cohortData %>% 
  group_by(cohort) %>%
    mutate(percentage = count/count[dayCount == 0])
#        cohort dayCount count percentage
#        <fctr>    <int> <int>      <dbl>
#1  25/10/2016        0   238 1.00000000
#2  25/10/2016        1   137 0.57563025
#3  25/10/2016        2    78 0.32773109
#4  25/10/2016        3    32 0.13445378
#5  25/10/2016        4    21 0.08823529
#6  25/10/2016        5    25 0.10504202
#7  26/10/2016        0   134 1.00000000
#8  26/10/2016        1    97 0.72388060
#9  26/10/2016        2    49 0.36567164
#10 26/10/2016        3    22 0.16417910
## ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: I must be really stupid as running this code doesnt show anything, just asks for more input, changing df to cohortData does nothing as well :/

EDIT: well I stand corrected! was missing a ) and a df name thank you